# Video streaming HDS Flussonic Erlyvideo

Tags: video-streaming

Is there anyone who has used earlyvideo flussonic to set pseudo streaming mp4?

I need example config line, smth. like:

{file, blablabla...}.

and manifest.f4m + target file + segments (link to download), and where place all of these.

Debian Squeeze, nginx, flussonic (run correctly)

I will be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{http, 8080}.
{file, "vod", "/var/movies"}.
{root, "wwwroot"}.

/etc/init.d/flussonic start

than go to `http://localhost:8080/#play`

Enter  vod/video.mp4 to play /var/movies/video.mp4

It is not pseudo streaming, it is HTTP streaming.

Comment: he needs manifest.f4m file (HDS) or index.m3u8 (HLS) in the same folder, which contains video.mp4. It is right?
Player can't find these files and fs is not working. What have to contain manifest in the simpliest case?

Comment: flussonic generates manifest.f4m ondemand. You don't need to do anything. index.m3u8 (HLS) is generated only in commercial version.